# Однородные или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение: Меры социальной поддержки предоставляются педработникам...,работающим и проживающим в сельской местности и рабочих поселках Нижегородской области и перешедшим на пенсию. У автора перед "и перешедшим" стоит запятая. По-моему, не надо, здесь нет интонации перечисления. Правильно я думаю? Или нужна запятая? Спасибо

Comment: _"педработникам...,работающим"_ ===  А вместо каких слов поставлено многоточие?

Comment: Так дословно: Меры социальной поддержки по оплате жилого помещения предоставляются педработникам государственных образовательных организаций и муниципальных образовательных организаций Нижегородской области, работающим и проживающим в сельской местности и рабочих поселках Нижегородской области и перешедшим на пенсию.(Автор решил объединить 2 пункта в один- про работающих и на пенсии). Кстати, работникам и работающих- так в законе прописано.

Comment: Тогда запятая перед "и" нужна: закрывает причастный оборот.  Хотя предложение всё же стоит перестроить.

Comment: но перешедшим на пенсию-тоже определение, относящееся к слову работникам, таких определений 3, они однородные, но первые два имеют между собой более тесную связь по сравнению с третьим, значит запятая не нужна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Меры социальной поддержки предоставляются педработникам...,работающим
>   и проживающим в сельской местности и рабочих поселках Нижегородской
>   области и перешедшим на пенсию.

ВАРИАНТ:

*Меры социальной поддержки предоставляются педработникам...,работающим и проживающим в сельской местности и рабочих поселках Нижегородской области, а также педработникам, перешедшим на пенсию...*

Comment: Перешедшим на пенсию? Разве на пенсию переходят?

Comment: Так говорят. См., к примеру, здесь: http://www.lexed.ru/praktika/sudebnaya-praktika/baza/detail.php?ELEMENT_ID=374

Comment: Интересно, что в этом документе нет единообразия в терминах: там и  выход на пенсию, и переход. Странно.